Who gets to select/know the identities of the Jurors in an anonymous Jury?
Do the prosecutors know who they are? What about the defense attorneys?
How does the usual process of jury selection even work in such a scenario?

Juries are not really anonymous. They sit in the courtroom. Sometimes the media is not told who they are. Is that what you mean?

Why would the attorneys need to know who they are? They can still ask questions in voir dire without asking the candidate to identify themselves.

@Cadence Because knowing parts of their identity (i.e. male/female/white/black/etc) would help in discerning if there is any unfair bias. But the act of knowing these details itself would progressively break anonymity.

The parties will typically receive a list of potential jurors, and that appears to have been the case here.
Both sides' attorneys will have access to that list, but they will be under court order not to reveal it to third parties.
If the court thinks the defendant himself may be part of the threat,I assume the court could release it to his defense team with an "attorneys eyes only" designation, which would prohibit them from sharing it with the defendant. As far as I know, that hasn't happened in Trump's case.

So, El Chapo's lawyers would've probably known who his jurors were? How would this protect anyone? Can't he just ask them?

With an AEO ddesignation, the client can ask, but the lawyers face contempt charges for answering. But in El Chapo's case, the judge went a step further due to the extraordinary circumstances and ordered complete anonymity; the jurors' identities were shielded not only from the defendant, but from his attorneys, the prosecutor, and the press, as well.

This answer cites nothing and predictably is false.

In most jurisdictions the jury sits in the courtroom. They can be seen by either side the whole time. They are not anonymous.
Sometimes the media is not told, so they do not try to speak to them.

I'm talking about an "anonymous jury" in cases where the jurors might be in danger.

They sit in the same room. I feel like you are misunderstanding not giving the media information. Give me an example though. @AlanSTACK

Judge, citing Trump’s ‘repeated public statements,’ orders anonymous jury in defamation suit trial
